# How do I combine the values in a nested array within a JS Object?

Tags: javascript, nested

I have a nested JS Object:

```
var object = {"person":{
  "id": "d54c54ad-40be-4305-8a34-0ab44710b90d",
  "name": {
    "fullName": "Alex MacCaw",
    "givenName": "Alex",
    "familyName": "MacCaw"
  },
  "email": "alex@alexmaccaw.com",
  "location": "San Francisco, CA, US",
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "utcOffset": -8,
  "geo": {
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "California",
    "stateCode": "CA",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "lat": 37.7749295,
    "lng": -122.4194155
  },
  "bio": "O'Reilly author, software engineer & traveller. Founder of https://clearbit.com",
  "site": "http://alexmaccaw.com",
  "avatar": "https://d1ts43dypk8bqh.cloudfront.net/v1/avatars/d54c54ad-40be-4305-8a34-0ab44710b90d",
  "employment": {
    "domain": "clearbit.com",
    "name": "Clearbit",
    "title": "Co-founder, CEO",
    "role": "leadership",
    "subRole": "ceo",
    "seniority": "executive"
  },
  "facebook": {
    "handle": "amaccaw"
  },
  "github": {
    "handle": "maccman",
    "avatar": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2142?v=2",
    "company": "Clearbit",
    "blog": "http://alexmaccaw.com",
    "followers": 2932,
    "following": 94
  },
  "twitter": {
    "handle": "maccaw",
    "id": "2006261",
    "bio": "O'Reilly author, software engineer & traveller. Founder of https://clearbit.com",
    "followers": 15248,
    "following": 1711,
    "location": "San Francisco",
    "site": "http://alexmaccaw.com",
    "avatar": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1826201101/297606_10150904890650705_570400704_21211347_1883468370_n.jpeg"
  },
  "linkedin": {
    "handle": "pub/alex-maccaw/78/929/ab5"
  },
  "googleplus": {
    "handle": null
  },
  "gravatar": {
    "handle": "maccman",
    "urls": [
      {
        "value": "http://alexmaccaw.com",
        "title": "Personal Website"
      }
    ],
    "avatar": "http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/994909da96d3afaf4daaf54973914b64",
    "avatars": [
      {
        "url": "http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/994909da96d3afaf4daaf54973914b64",
        "type": "thumbnail"
      }
    ]
  },
  "fuzzy": false,
  "emailProvider": false,
  "indexedAt": "2016-11-07T00:00:00.000Z"
},
"company": {
  "id": "3f5d6a4e-c284-4f78-bfdf-7669b45af907",
  "name": "Uber",
  "legalName": "Uber Technologies, Inc.",
  "domain": "uber.com",
  "domainAliases": [
    "uber.org",
    "ubercab.com"
  ],
  "site": {
    "phoneNumbers": [],
    "emailAddresses": [
      "domains@uber.com"
    ]
  },
  "category": {
    "sector": "Information Technology",
    "industryGroup": "Software & Services",
    "industry": "Internet Software & Services",
    "subIndustry": "Internet Software & Services",
    "sicCode": "47",
    "naicsCode": "51"
  },
  "tags": [
    "Technology",
    "Marketplace",
    "Mobile",
    "B2C",
    "Ground Transportation",
    "Transportation",
    "Internet"
  ],
  "description": "Get a taxi, private car or rideshare from your mobile phone. Uber connects you with a driver in minutes. Use our app in cities around the world.",
  "foundedYear": 2009,
  "location": "1455 Market St, San Francisco, CA 94103, USA",
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "utcOffset": -7,
  "geo": {
    "streetNumber": "1455",
    "streetName": "Market Street",
    "subPremise": null,
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "postalCode": "94103",
    "state": "California",
    "stateCode": "CA",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "lat": 37.7752315,
    "lng": -122.4175278
  },
  "logo": "https://logo.clearbit.com/uber.com",
  "facebook": {
    "handle": "uber"
  },
  "linkedin": {
    "handle": "company/uber-com"
  },
  "twitter": {
    "handle": "Uber",
    "id": "19103481",
    "bio": "Evolving the way the world moves by seamlessly connecting riders to drivers through our app. Question, concern, or praise? Tweet at @Uber_Support.",
    "followers": 570351,
    "following": 377,
    "location": "Global",
    "site": "http://something.com/11eIV5LX3Z",
    "avatar": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/697242369154940928/p9jxYqy5_normal.png"
  },
  "crunchbase": {
    "handle": "organization/uber"
  },
  "emailProvider": false,
  "type": "private",
  "ticker": null,
  "identifiers": {
    "usEIN": "452647441"
  },
  "phone": null,
  "indexedAt": "2016-11-07T00:00:00.000Z",
  "metrics": {
    "alexaUsRank": 544,
    "alexaGlobalRank": 943,
    "employees": 20313,
    "employeesRange": "10k-50k",
    "marketCap": null,
    "raised": 10610000000,
    "annualRevenue": null,
    "estimatedAnnualRevenue": "$1B-$10B",
    "fiscalYearEnd": 12
  },
  "tech": [
    "optimizely",
    "tealium",
    "atlassian_confluence",
    "workday",
    "talend",
    "oracle_peoplesoft",
    "salesforce",
    "teradata",
    "apache_kafka",
    "aws_dynamodb",
    "grafana",
    "factset",
    "dropbox"
  ],
  "techCategories": [
    "analytics",
    "advertising",
    "productivity",
    "human_capital_management",
    "data_management",
    "business_management",
    "crm",
    "monitoring"
  ],
  "parent": {
    "domain": null
  },
  "ultimateParent": {
    "domain": null
  }
} }
```

I have setup a script to help me iterate through the object and return the keys with their parents as name attributes on inputs, and then the value of that line item as the value of the input.
In the case that the value is an object I am jumping into that object and finding the first instance where the value is not an object and then returning that key plus parent keys and the value as the name of the input and the value of the input, respectively. For instance in the snippet below I won't return  I would jump inside the company and return  and so on. This all works fine:

```
"company": {
  "id": "3f5d6a4e-c284-4f78-bfdf-7669b45af907",
  "name": "Uber",
  "legalName": "Uber Technologies, Inc.",
  "domain": "uber.com",
  "domainAliases": [
    "uber.org",
    "ubercab.com"
  ],
```

What I am having trouble with is that there are instances of the value being an array. In these instances I want the array of values to be concatenated as one single comma delineated string and have that be set as the value for the last key before the array. In the above I would be looking for the output to be the following:

```
<input name="companyId" value="3f5d6a4e-c284-4f78-bfdf-7669b45af907" />
<input name="companyName" value="Uber" />
<input name="companyLegalName" value="Uber Technologies, Inc." />
<input name="companyDomain" value="uber.com" />
<input name="companyDomainAliases" value="uber.org, ubercab.com" /> <!-- note this line is an array in the JSON object -->
```

My code is below:

```
function iterate(obj, stack) {
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                    iterate(obj[property], stack + property.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + property.slice(1));
                } else {
                    console.log(stack.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + stack.slice(1) + property.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + property.slice(1) + " : " + obj[property]);
                    var content = document.getElementById('detailForm');
                    var formInput = document.createElement("input");
                    var formInputName = stack.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + stack.slice(1) + property.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + property.slice(1);
                    var formInputValue = obj[property];
                    formInput.setAttribute('name', formInputName);
                    formInput.setAttribute('value', formInputValue);
                    content.appendChild(formInput);
                }
            }
        }
    }

iterate(object, '')
```

What I'm wanting the output to be for the example above is:

```
<input name="companyDomainAliases" value="uber.org, ubercab.com">
```

I have a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/TheDesignerXD/pen/qBNqaOL) with my current working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is modification of your code. I added an extra parameter to try and keep your overall structure and to produce your desired outcome and preventing repetitive call on array element.

```
function iterate(obj, stack,sublist) 
{ 

  for (var property in obj) 
    {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) 
        {
            if (typeof obj[property] == "object" && obj[property]) 
            {
                var subL = null;
                if(obj[property] && obj[property].length>1) 
                { 
                  subL =obj[property];
                }
                iterate(obj[property], stack + property.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + property.slice(1),subL);
            }
            else 
            {
               var valueStr=obj[property];
               var lastPart = property.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + property.slice(1);
                
               if(sublist) 
               {
                 var i;
                 valueStr = sublist[0] ;
                  for (i = 1; i < sublist.length; i++) 
                  {
                    valueStr += ","+sublist[i];
                  } 
                 lastPart = "";
                 //console.log(valueStr);
                } 
                 
                 //console.log(stack.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + stack.slice(1) + property.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + property.slice(1) + " : " + obj[property]);
                
                var content = document.getElementById('detailForm');
                var formInput = document.createElement("input");
                var formInputName = stack.charAt(0).toLowerCase() +  stack.slice(1)  + lastPart;
                var formInputValue = valueStr;
                formInput.setAttribute('name', formInputName);
                formInput.setAttribute('value', formInputValue);
                // formInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                content.appendChild(formInput);
               //if(sublist) 
               // console.log(formInput);
            }
         }
         if(obj==sublist)
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I first thought the other was the correct answer. But upon further inspection it is clear that yours is the more correct answer. Thank you for your detailed breakdown and the console logs helped me test it a bit more as well. :)

Comment: I'm glad to be of help :D